# Google AppInvite

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Реализовал в приложении `Google` `AppInvite`:

- прописал в `build.gradle` (project level)
- прописал в `build.gradle` (app level)
- добавил `java` код в класс
- создал ключ в `Console Google Developer`
- скопировал `*.json` файл в директорию `/app` своего проекта

Запустил приложение и получил `APPINVITE_CLIENT_ID_ERROR`.
Или, если быть точным, то

```
E/AppInviteAgent: Get suggested invitees failed due to error code: 3
                No Android client ID is found for package name <MY_PACKAGE_NAME>. (APPINVITE_CLIENT_ID_ERROR)

E/AppInviteAgent: Create invitations failed due to error code: 3
                No Android client ID is found for package name <MY_PACKAGE_NAME>. (APPINVITE_CLIENT_ID_ERROR)
```

Гуглил проблему, на enSO в одном только вопросе было сказано, что ошибка в том, что ключи разные (SHA-1 в приложении и в `Console`). Но они не могут быть разными, я же `*.json` файл в проект скопировал, а его мне `Google` сгенерировал.

Подключил LogCat, словил такое: `onActivityResult: requestCode=0, resultCode=3`
Это отображается, если отправка не получилась.

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерируйте *.json еще раз. У меня такое было

Comment: Генерировал его раза 2-3, результата никакого.

Comment: А у вас случайно не разные аккаунты в console и в android studio? Возможно нужно создать новый SHA в студио. Откройте json и сравните с тем что показывает студия.

Comment: В студии нет вообще никакого аккаунта, я не логинился.

Comment: Возможно что дело в этом, я в своём приложении долго не мог понять почему не генерирует токен для Firebase Cloud Message, пока не увидел, что у меня разные аккаунты в студии и в консоли. Зашёл в студии в аккаунт как и в консоли, все заработало.

Comment: Сегодня вечером проверю Ваше предложение.